# In .Net Remoting, if you don't specify a remoting service in a configuration file or register one in code, what default settings are used?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

**Context**

I've inherited a .NET Remoting application which is having a problem where clients hang when trying to register shared objects with the server.  This registration occurs an arbitrary period of time after the server is started with a call to 'register' on a shared ILease object.

In the process of following the code path, I am trying to figure out where calls to `RemotingServices.Marshal` and `RemotingServices.RegisterWellKnownSericeType` are storing their information. My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311041/in-net-remoting-what-or-where-specifically-is-the-net-remoting-framework)'s answer lead me to understand that applications specify the service that stores this information in either the .exe's configuation file, or using the `RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType` call, as corroborated [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29945/All-you-need-to-know-about-NET-Remoting).

**Question**

Our application uses neither a configuration file nor `RegisterWellKnownClientType` to register a remoting service, but uses .NET remoting successfully. I haven't been able to figure out from .NET's open-source reference code or from the articles through which I've looked what 'default' service is used for .NET Remoting. So, does anyone know what the default settings used for .NET Remoting service are?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347348/andy) in the comments of the linked question, the answer is that there's a third option for registering a communication system for the .NET Remoting runtime: [directly registering a TCP channel object with the remoting services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2eeyt4ba(v=vs.110).aspx). E.g.:

```
TcpChannel.TcpChannel ipcChannel = new TcpChannel(...);
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannel( ipcChannel, false );
```